# Cassandra update and sort on same column

Tags: sorting, cassandra, updating, timeline, timeuuid

I'm looking for some inputs around cassandra data modelling for a timeline kind of feature. To store data for the timeline, I'm planning to use `timeuuid` in cassandra and make it as a clustering key. This will help in sorting the data. But the same data can be updated and I need to store the updated timeuuid corresponding the data so that it can be pushed up in the timeline. This involves fetching the previous data-timeuuid row, delete it and insert the new one. But doesn't seem to performant. How can I handle the sorting and updating on the same column (in my case timeuuid) to implement timeline feature.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this schema to you :

```
CREATE TABLE timeline_idx {
    timeline_key text,
    time timeuuid,
    content_key text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((partition_key), time)
}

CREATE TABLE timeline_content {
    content_key text,
    content blob,
    PRIMARY KEY (content_key)
}
```

Timeline_idx is used to give you the content keys ordered as a timeline. Then you can retrieve the content in a second table called timeline_content. It is not ordered and there is no clustering key. You can update your content without knowing its timeuuid. I choose text type for timeline_key and content_key but you can choose whatever you want as long as it identifies timelines and contents uniquely.

Comment: Still the same issue because he wants to have the timestamp updated as well as content of a post. Would need to delete from timeline_idx and do a new insert. Not sure what the best model is here.

Comment: Or just do a new insert. Client could filter on distinct content_key from timeline_idx.